# How can I write the docker -it option in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want create a Dockerfile for CMD line:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server
```

How I do -it in Dockerfile?

Comment: You are running a Docker container in a Docker container for building in image? Are you sure that this is really what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the "interactive" (`-i`) and "tty" (`-t`) runtime options from the Dockerfile at build time. You'll need to include that in the documentation for how to use your image.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a string instead of an array in CMD Dockerfile instruction.
So you can type:

```
CMD "docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server"
```

Otherwise "-it" should be an element of CMD array.